# Retrieve the return value of a function used in threading.Timer method

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, pywinauto

I have a function `check_is_window_open` which checks if a Windows application is open or not ? If the application is open then it will return 1 else 0

Here is the function :

```
from pywinauto import Application,keyboard
def check_is_window_open():
    try:
        app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title='Some Application')
        window = app['Some Application']
        return 1
    except:
        return 0
```

This application window takes several minutes to open. So I want to check for every 10 seconds if the window is open. If it is open then I will do some automation else I will keep checking.

```
from threading import Timer
def my_automation():
    Timer(10,check_is_window_open).start()
    #if the return of check_is_window_open is 0 then I will keep checking
    #else I will cancel the timer and perform my automation.
```

Now the question is how to retrieve the return value of `check_is_window_open` ?

Comment: Threads are used when you want to do something else while waiting. If you just want to wait for a window to open, `time.sleep(10)` in a loop will do. Could you explain exactly why you need the threads?

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(10)` is a hard-coded wait, it's much better to use flexible waits provided by pywinauto: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html

There are many ways to wait something: window is open/closed/enabled/disabled, app eats CPU or not (to detect lazy initialization without appearing new control/window).